# Computing the center of a group $G = \langle s,t \mid s^8=t^2=1, st=ts^3 \rangle $

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to find

> The number of nonisomoprhic simple modules of $\mathbb{C}G$, where  $G = \langle s,t \mid s^8=t^2=1, st=ts^3 \rangle$.

This is equivalent to (I think, by Artin-Wedderburn) the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. We may represent any element in $G$ in the form $s^kt^l$ for $1 \le k \le 8, 1 \le l \le 2$, using the relations. So

> How does one compute the number of conjugacy classes of $G$? Any hints?

Comment: I am finding your question confusing, because we do know $G$ explicitly. It is a group of order $16$ with centre  of order $2$. Also the number of simple modules is equal to the number of conjugacy classes, not the size of its centre.

Comment: How do you know its center is of order 2? And yes, you are right,  it is not the size of center, I will edit question now.

Comment: This is known as the semidihedral group of order $16$. $t$ conjugates $s$ to $s^3$, hence $s^2$ to $s^6$, and $s^4$ to $s^{12} = s^4$, so it is not bard to see that the centre is $\{ 1, s^4 \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sketch of the calculation of the conjugacy classes. As I said in my comment, $t$ conjugates $s$ to $s^3$, $s^2$ to $s^6$, and it centralizes $s^4$, so the conjugacy classes contained in $\langle s \rangle$ are $\{ 1 \}$, $\{ s^4 \}$, $\{s,s^3\}$, and $\{s^2,s^6\}$.

Also, $sts^{-1}= ts^3s^{-1} = ts^2$, $s(ts^2)s^{-1} = ts^4$ and $s(ts^4)s^{-1}= ts^6$, so another class is $\{ t,ts^2,ts^4,ts^6 \}$, and similarly there is a class $\{ ts,ts^3,ts^5,ts^7 \}$, making $7$ classes altogether.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. I have one last question. Suppose you did not know this was the semidihedral group of order $16$, how are you sure the elements, $t^js^k$ are all distinct, $0 \le j \le 1, 0 \le k \le 7$. ?


The way I thought of proving this is to explicitly show the set $G':= \{ t^js^k \}$ with the defined operation is indeed a group. We can then construct an isomorphism $G \cong G'$.

Comment: The map $s \mapsto s^3$ induces an automorphism of the cyclic group of order $8$ generated by $s$. So the group is actually a semidirect product of $\langle s \rangle$ and $\langle t \rangle$, and hence has order $8 \times 2 = 16$.